# Trying to rewrite an array value on iteration stores only the first character

Tags: php, arrays

Data is an array of arrays, each of which is two elements in size.
I'm trying to rewrite each of first element to string 'hello', but on var_dump see only the first character 'h'.

```
function replace() {
   foreach($this->data as $record)
      $this->data[$record[0]] = 'hello';
}

function print_array() {
   foreach($this->data as $record)
      var_dump($record[0]);
```

How can I write the whole word?

Comment: I think that you have to do directly $record[0]='hello'.

Comment: Is `$this->data` an associative array or an indexed array? Could you show us what it looks like?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is an indexed array of arrays. I think I referring to the element not correct. Is it any was to write to the pointer of the current array processed? Something like &$record[0] ?

Comment: @MarcoMorelliMoretti if I will do so, on var_dump($record[0]) will not change at all, I guess it is because of the function scope.

Comment: Have you tried passing the variable $record by reference? In foresch add &$record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `$record[0]` contains the value, not they key.

#### With for

Since `$this->data` is an indexed array, you can do this:

```
function replace()
{
    $count = count($this->data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $this->data[$i][0] = 'Hello';
    }
}
```

#### With foreach

If you rather want to use `foreach`:

```
function replace()
{
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
        // We're not gonna use $value here, since it's just a copy
        $this->data[$key][0] = 'Hello';
    }
}
```

#### With foreach and references

If you rather want to use `foreach` and references *(notice the `&`-sign before `$value` in the foreach)*:

```
function replace()
{
    foreach ($this->data as &$value) {
        // Now we can use $value directly, since it's a reference
        $value[0] = 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! Chosen solution number two for readability, but references of course the elegant one :)

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, declare the `$key` and use that when adding/printing elements to your array.

```
class Test {

    private $data = [
                        ['test1', 'my1', 'name1'],
                        ['test2', 'my2', 'name2']

                    ];

    private function replace() {

        foreach ($this->data as $k=>$v) {

                $this->data[$k][0] = 'hello';  
        }
    }

   public function print_array() {

      $this->replace();
      foreach($this->data as $k=>$v) {

          echo $this->data[$k][0];
          echo '<br>';

      }
   }  
}

//Object
$new = new Test();
$new->print_array();
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hello
```